# Change the vertical spacing option "tight" in shorttoc

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, shorttoc

I'm generating a short table of contents using the [shorttoc-package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shorttoc).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[tight]{shorttoc}

\begin{document}

\shorttoc{Shorttoc}{1}
\tableofcontents

\section{Sec1}
\subsection{Subs1}
\section{Sec2}
\subsection{Subs2}
\section{Sec3}
\subsection{Subs3}

\end{document}
```

The [package documentation](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/shorttoc/shorttoc.pdf) states, that the option `tight` should reduce the vertical spacing between the entries in the shorttoc, but in my  example it doesn't. I suspect, this is due to this part of [shorttoc.sty](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/shorttoc/shorttoc.sty)?

```
\newif\if@tightshtoc \@tightshtocfalse
\def\shorttableofcontents#1#2{\bgroup\c@tocdepth=#2\@restonecolfalse
  \if@tightshtoc
     \parsep\z@
  \fi
```

What do I have to do to resize the vertical spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `\parsep` is the vertical space between paragraphs of a list item, I'm at a loss why redefining it should change the spacing between ToC lines. For section entries, the latter is controlled by the `\l@section` macro (which contains the line `\addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}`), and this macro needs to be redefined. If you want to change the spacing only for the short ToC, the redefinition must be done inside a group. (Note: I'm using the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and its `\patchcmd` macro for convenience.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{%
  \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}% original code line
}{%
  \addvspace{0.3em \@plus 0.3\p@}% substitute code line
}{}{}
\makeatother
\shorttoc{Shorttoc}{1}
\endgroup

\tableofcontents

\section{Sec1}
\subsection{Subs1}
\section{Sec2}
\subsection{Subs2}
\section{Sec3}
\subsection{Subs3}

\end{document}
```